# WS02 ESB :proxy service

Tags: wso2, esb

The EIP ( iteration & aggregation pattern code works as expected. The EIPProxy service has the implementation for the Interator and aggregation to give the desired result. In this implementation, the Iterator in turn invoked another transformer proxy which generates the individuiaal message in a specific format.

However when the EIP proxy is invoked as part of a composite service, it somehow fails to invoke the iterator end point proxy after going through the EIPProxy.
the exception message returned is

```
INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[serviceurl for the main proxy]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:450)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:398)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:272)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the error says "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
check you endpoint status`